# If the photon hasn't an electric and magnetic field yet, then what does its polarization vector stand for?

Tags: photons, quantum-electrodynamics, polarization

In the context of quantum electrodynamics, The photon field is described by a operators connected to a Fock space of photon states $e^{-ip_{\mu}x^{\mu}}$.

The relativistic photon wavefunction can be associated from the Maxwell equations but the electric and magnetic fields don't apply to the photon. A point-like particle without charge doesn't produce an EM field. But it's not an EM unit either. The macroscopic EM field comes into play for lots of photons in a coherent state only.

If a photon interacts with a charged particle, it delivers an energy and momentum. It can be scattered or absorbed.

How is the photon described without the E and B field? What is the significance of the polarization vector (which can combine to the Jonas vector) if not associated with an EM field? What's exactly polarized?

Comment: If you know already classical electrodynamics, you know that E and B fields come from the four-potential. The photon field is precisely this last one.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux Yes, but the A-field is a classical relativistic concept. Does the photon itself have an A-field? How can we associate a polarization for a single photon? It's spin, which can have two independent directions, perpendicular to the direction of motion? Or is the A-field associated with the probability to find one?

Comment: As I said, the A field (there is only one) is the field of photons. This means we quantize A, and define a quantum of it as being a photon. All the 1st and 2nd quantization machinery is applied to the field, meaning we have polarization vectors, spin, energy, momentum, etc. I recommend you read a lecture on QFT, there are plenty online.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux Well, I understand the quantizing of the A-field by Fourier expansion and creation/destruction operators, which are associated with "wavefunctions" of a photon. And there is only the A-field (unique in a chosen gauge), but it's more the interpretation of the polarization. If it has two independent directions then what does that mean? Okay , that the A-field has two directions?

Comment: Basically, the "polarization vector" $\hat{\bf A}$ (which is not the classical four-potential $\bf A$) doesn't have a direct physical meaning but we can construct the electric and magnetic field *operators* from it.